# OS X clang rpy2

Tags: r, macos, python-3.x, clang

I'm trying to install the python library rpy2 in OS X (El Capitan) with R 3.4.
I did follow many posts on web and I end up replacing clang from xcode to one manually installed (after following http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#clang-before-3-4-0):

```
clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Still, when I tried to install rpy2 (sudo pip3 install rpy2):

```
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6 -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
    ld: library not found for -lomp
    clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

What's lomp? I'm not sure what I can do now.

UPDATE:
I try to reinstall llvm through brew:

```
brew reinstall --with-clang --with-lld --with-python --HEAD llvm
```

now installing rpy2 I got:

```
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6 -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
    ld: library not found for -lomp
    clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Although from the llvm installation I got the advice:

```
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
```

do you know how to set it? It may be the reason it fails

Comment: OMP is the [OpenMP library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). Your clang (Apple’s fork) seems to not support it (I can reproduce this problem with my LLVM 7.0, albeit with a slightly different message). According to what I could find, you might want to try `brew install llvm`.

Comment: I did already but no luck. Btw my clang shouldn't be my apple (xcode) version but another one I found in the link http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#clang-before-3-4-0

Comment: Right, I misread the version line. At any rate, the issue is that OpenMP cannot be found by your compiler. It needs to be reinstalled, configured with support for OpenMP. Unfortunately I don’t know how to do this (and my own installation is similarly shot).

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed on the rpy2 issue tracker: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340

Note that the issue was resolved and a precompiled binary wheel for rpy2-2.9.3 is now available on pypi.